# Euler circle and Hamilton cycles

Tags: graph-theory

Given $K_n$ define sequence $S_4$:  writing all vertices in order of traversing it by Euler circle

How many distinct Hamilton cycles are in this sequence $S$?

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: I think the best answer, based upon the answers below, is that it depends on the sequence you're talking about.  As stated, the sequence isn't well defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can certainly vary.  As an Eulerean path uses all $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ edges and a Hamiltonian path uses $n$, you can't have more than $\frac{n-1}{2}$.  Can you have that many?  There aren't any Eulerean paths if $n$ is even and $>2$.  Depending upon your definition, I can define an Eulearean path that has no segment that is Hamiltonian

Comment: Wouldn't an Eulerian path use all $n(n+1)/2$ edges?

Comment: Obviously no segment, but I think this is talking about sequences of edges that make a Hamiltonian path.

Comment: @Hans Parshall: You are right.  Fixed (I hope).  Thanks

Comment: You fixed it better than I did.

Answer (score 3):

The question does not seem to be very precise.

In any case,

It is [well known](http://books.google.com/books?id=PuL2KC_KCj0C&pg=PA21) that $K_{2k+1}$ can be decomposed into $k$ hamiltonian cycles.

So we can find an Euler tour with exactly $\dfrac{n-1}{2}$ hamiltonian cycles for odd $n$.

For even $n$, we can do an "incomplete tour" with  $\dfrac{n}{2}-1$ (See link above) hamiltonian cycles.

Comment: For even n, there aren't any Eulerian tours.

Comment: @Jacob: Yes, I meant we can get close... Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't necessarily *any* Hamiltonian cycles in your sequence.

As Ross already pointed out, provided $n$ is even and $n > 2$, then all vertices have odd degree and no Eulerian circuit exists.  So, we need only worry about when $n$ is odd and $n > 3$.

For $K_5$ arranged as in the picture, an Eulerian circuit with no Hamiltonian cycles is given by

[image: $K_5$]

$$1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 5 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 5 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 1.$$

Now suppose $K_{n-2}$ has an Eulerian circuit with no Hamiltonian cycles.  First label the vertices of $K_n$ as $1, \ldots, n$.  Our Eulerian circuit with no Hamiltonian cycles for $K_n$ is given by first travelling $1 \rightarrow 2$, then travelling the Eulerian circuit with no Hamiltonian cycles for $K_{n-2}$ across the vertices $2, \ldots, n-1$, arriving back at $2$.  Then for $k = 2, 4, 6, \ldots, n - 3$, we travel $$k \rightarrow n \rightarrow k + 1 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow k + 2.$$  Finally, we travel $n-1 \rightarrow n \rightarrow 1.$

It follows from induction that $K_n$ contains an Eulerian circuit with no Hamiltonian cycles for all odd $n$.